# First countable + separable imply second countable?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separable-spaces, second-countable, first-countable

In topological space, does first countable+ separable imply second countable? If not, any counterexample?

Comment: Some counterexamples are listed in one of the answers to [this previous Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356595/does-seperable-first-countable-sigma-locally-finite-basis-imply-second-count).

Comment: However, the implication does hold for topological *groups*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It’s false in general. A simple counterexample is the [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology), also known as $\Bbb R$ with the lower limit topology: $\Bbb Q$ is still a dense set, and each point $x$ has a countable local base of sets of the form $\left[x,x+\frac1n\right)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, but the space is not second countable.

The [Sorgenfrey plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane), the Cartesian product of the Sorgenfrey line with itself, is even worse: $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ is a dense subset, so it’s separable, and as a product of two first countable spaces it is certainly first countable, but the reverse diagonal, $\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x\in\Bbb R\}$, is an uncountable closed discrete set. It’s easy to see that no space with an uncountable closed discrete subset can be second countable.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology)!